Distribution on antisymmetric matrices whose pushforward under matrix exponential is Haar-uniform
The matrix exponential of an antisymmetric matrix is a special orthogonal matrix.
There is a uniform distribution on the set of special orthogonal matrices $\text{SO}(n)$, namely the Haar measure.
Question: For general $n$, what is a distribution on the set of $n \times n$ antisymmetric matrices whose pushforward under the exponential map is uniform?
For example, for $n = 2$, it suffices to use
$$\theta \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
where $\theta \sim \text{Uniform}(-\pi, \pi)$.
Ideally, the distribution should be easy to sample from.
One idea might be to sample uniformly from $\text{SO}(n)$ and then apply matrix logarithm. However, the logarithm of a special orthogonal matrix is not necessarily antisymmetric (see here and here).
